# Number of vertices in a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the number of vertices in a rooted ternary (?, I'm sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology, English is not my native language) (each node has no more than 3 children) tree with 2017 leaves.

Could someone give me a hint as to how to tackle this problem? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think this problem needs more assumptions. You can always attach a new vertex to a leaf, which maintains the number of leaves while increasing the number of vertices.

Comment: Did you maybe mean a balanced rooted ternary tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean that each node has **no more than $3$ children**, there are infinitely many possibilities.  Because given any suitable tree, we can give one of the leaves a child, retaining $2017$ leaves while adding one more vertex.

If you mean that each node (other than leaves) has **exactly $3$ children**, then the number of vertices is $3025$.

**Proof** using the handshaking lemma - the sum of all degrees is twice the number of edges.  Let $v$ be the number of vertices.  Then the number of edges is $v-1$.  The tree has

- one vertex (the root) of degree $3$;
- $2017$ vertices (the leaves) of degree $1$;
- $v-2018$ vertices (the others) of degree $4$.

So
$$3+2017+4(v-2018)=2(v-1)$$
and solving gives $v=3025$.